# How to filter ALL values in a column using Google Apps Script? [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a filter, which I want to sort on column H. I want to hide all values in the column. The values in this column are constantly changing so the script must be dynamic / able to hide all values as they change.

I have spent considerable time but cannot find any script for this purpose. Any advice or direction is welcome!!

The ultimate goal for this script is that after I have hidden all values in the column, I want to show only 1 of those values.

Comment: There are no triggers which fire on cells changing their values due to formulas or other scripts.

Comment: if you wish to hide cells you could conceivably make their background color the same as their font color or vice versa

Comment: Hi there Nagaram92! Besides what Cooper said in his comment, could you please describe the update frequency of those formulas?